# prolog, taking only first answer

Tags: prolog

I've read some topics on this subjects, but I can't get it to work. Assume I have following predicate:

```
wins(L,K,X):-member(X,L),X>=K.
wins(L,K,X):-member(X,L),X<K,K1 is K-X,\+wins(L,K1,_).
```

It doesn't really matter what it does, the thing is that for example:

```
?- wins([1,4],1,X).
X = 1;
X = 4;
false.
```

Now, this predicate helps me to check to find if some condition can be fulfilled and gives the numbers that allow to achieve this. That's OK, but now I would only like to get the first asnwer, which is `X = 1` here and then make Prolog stop searching. Yet, I can't use `!`, becuase then it finds the `X = 1` and return `false`. And I need it to return `true`, in case I have other following conditions based on resulting X, like:

```
play(L,K,X):- member(X,L),K1 is K-X,K1>0,wins(L,K1,Y),K2 is K1-Y, ...
```

Then in `...` I want to be able to use **only the first one result** from `win` predicate. I need to use SWI-Prolog.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Maybe I should expand it more, because `once()` is working, but not exactly as I would like to. I mean if I wanted to wait for the user input, let's say:

```
play(L,K,X):-
    member(X, L),
    K1 is K-X,
    K1 > 0,
    once(wins(L, K1, Y)),
    K2 is K1 - Y,
    write('Something: '),
    read(Z),
    ...
```

In that case on the output I would get:
`Something: |:`

After I press any portion of text (to read Z), let's say `'THIS'`, it goes like:
`SomethingTHIS`.

What I mean is that some part of the previous text put into output disappears (in this case it's `': '` that's missing).

Any idead how I could fix this?

Comment: Shouldn't you just put the cut inside `play/3` instead of `wins/3`?

Comment: @gusbro I've tried, but then Prolog is waiting for my input with `|:` and I would like to let him know- "hey, show me You know it's done without my approval'! :)

Comment: @Kay But where? Putting `!` after `wins(L,K1,Y)` will return false, and next conditions won't be checked. At the end of the predicate it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Please check my edit:)